A scene from 80s fantasy show- diving into a lagoon full of treasure, touch an item, turning to gold- maybe based off a book/legend- maybe BBC
Does anyone remember the BBC Narnia series from the late 80s? 
What I'm thinking of may be a scene from that, but I'm not quite sure - my brain is at the very least clumping it with that era/style meaning possibly also a BBC fantasy show maybe based on a book/legend. 
Maybe its from an episode of an anthology show like Faerie Tale Theatre or something. I mostly just have some images/ideas in my head that are too vague to place, and its driving me nuts. 
There's a pool of water in a forest and there is treasure at the bottom and if you touch one of them (a mirror?) or aren't worthy or something then you turn to gold. I want to say that a boy was sent on the quest to save/retrieve someone or something and was too cocky and got turned to gold and so then his sibling (I want to say sister?) runs away to find/save him and ends up the worthy one.
Sorry this is so obscure and quite possible not remembered accurately- hopefully the answer to this will come to me in the middle of the night as these types of memories so often do.

There is a scene in "Voyage of the Dawn Treader"...the third movie/book in the Chronicles of Narnia series that fits the bill.
The movie version on youtube




I found the whole BBC Narnia series at youtube....here's that sequence in that series.




Yes! Thank you so much. I never got around to seeing the third of the recent movies, and i haven't read the books in forever, but I was definitely thinking of this BBC version. My mind is at ease ;)
